# Paging ListView With DataPager and skip, take

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listview, datapager

i use this code for paging Listview control in asp.net.

[Paging ListView With DataPager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24065/Paging-ListView-With-DataPager)

but i want use skip and take for paging Listview.

I did a lot of searching  but could not find the correct answer

Comment: what do you try to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To do true custom paging where you only get the exact records that will be displayed on the current page, then you will need to use some form of LINQ provider (LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities, etc.), because the `.Skip()` and `.Take()` methods will not be able to provide that custom paging context without being able to influence the query for retrieving the data from the database.

In other words, the paging power of `.Skip()` and `.Take()` on the entire list of the total records of all the pages is significantly weakened when applied as LINQ to Objects, because it will not be able to provide just a single page of data.

In short, you need to decide which LINQ to XYZ flavor of database functionality you want to use that allows for `.Skip()` and `.Take()` to truly exercise efficient, custom paging on your behalf.

If you decide to use LINQ to SQL, then you should check out the [LinqDataSource class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.aspx), specifically the [AutoPage property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.autopage.aspx), because that is a built-in use of the `.Skip()` and `.Take()` functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Can you explain why Skip and Take would not work correctly using LINQ to Objects? e.g. if you were to write someObjects.Skip(20).Take(10), would this not give the same results in LINQ to Objects and LINQ to SQL?

Comment: @RyanDansie - LINQ to Objects works with `IEnumerable` objects, while LINQ to XYZ flavor works with `IQueryable` objects. The difference is that `IQueryable` is data that gets parsed by a LINQ provider, for example LINQ to SQL takes the `IQueryable` data and parses it into T-SQL statements. LINQ to Objects using `.Skip()` and `.Take()` can provide a custom paging-like experience, but only if the entire `IEnumerable` collection is in memory, which for huge data sets (think 100,000 rows in a database table) that is generally not the case and even if it was would be a huge resource hog.